# Is there a short version of this C# property declaration?

Tags: c#

I'm refactoring some code due to a change in the parameters of a constructor. I'm looking for the most clear and minimalistic way of declaring the properties of this class.

In this example it's `Button` that has changed constructor from previously taking parameters to not.

Originally the properties would look like this:

```
public Button Person
{
    get
    {
        if (AppPlatform == Platform.XYZ) return new Button(x => x.Id("imagePerson"));
        else return new Button(x => x.Id("c_person"));
    }
}
```

After changing the Button class constructor, I've come up with this way of declaring the properties, but I find it looks too "big" or clonky.

```
public Button Person
{
    get
    {
        if (AppPlatform == Platform.XYZ)
            controlIdQuery = x => x.Id("imagePerson");
        else
            controlIdQuery = x => x.Id("c_person");

        return this;
    }
}
```

Besides, I'd add the properties through composition to various classes like this:

```
public Button Person => new Buttons().Person;
```

so I'm not even sure the property should return `this`. Can it return just itself like `return Person`?

The clonkyness becomes even worse when I need to embed Button in a class that do not have access to `controlIdQuery` through inheritance:

```
public Button Down
{
    get
    {
        Button b = new Button { controlIdQuery = x => x.Id("imagePerson") };
        return b;
    }
}
```

TL;DR: Is there a short hand version of this type of property declaration?

Comment: The question doesn't make much sense. A *property* returns a *property* of an object. Not the object itself, and not part of another temporary object that may get disposed or invalidated. What is `Person` supposed to do? Why does it return a *new* instance each time it's called? Shouldn't it be a method in that case?

Comment: I'm with Panagiotis on this one too. Are you sure this isn't better as a method? Especially as each property access is returning a completely new object each time, it's not intuitive.

Comment: A property should not return a new object every time, nor the whole instance. And a getter should definitely not *set* something! You should review the best practices about properties.

Comment: I think you are overcomplicating things. The Platform won't change during the course of execution of the App, right? So why not use a Factory and initialize the Factory to be the appropriate implementation for the platform at hand? And then as the others already said: A property returning a new instance on each call seems just not right.

Comment: A property that gives you something different every time you access it? So `blah.Person != blah.Person`? Hmm. That's unexpected.

Comment: @spender Other than the memory address of the returned object, it's the same object returned for the entire lifetime of the program, since AppPlatform do not change during execution.

Comment: if the memory adress is different it´s another instance, which doesn´t make much sense IMHO.

Comment: @PebermynteLars If a property returns a `new` object, it's a different object every time, not the same object.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://www.dofactory.com/net/abstract-factory-design-pattern I think it is what you want.